# Unable to gzip the file in the same location on Solaris

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to find file bigger than 1 GB and zipping the content, and after the file is zipped, I need to delete the tar file and nullify the existing file. But here while gzipping the file, it's not gzipping to the same path; it's going to the user's home directory. This is on Solaris servers.

I am running this from remote server.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeychecking=no  -qt 192.168.1.1 "$(<.fs1.sh)"
```

This is what `.fs1.sh` contains:

```
threshold="50"
date=`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
for fs in $(df -k / /var /tmp| awk '{print $6}' | sed '1 d'); do
    chk=$(df -k ${fs} | sed '1 d' | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F\% '{print $1}')
    if [ ${chk} -gt ${threshold} ]; then
        /usr/local/bin/sudo rm -f /tmp/files.log
        /usr/local/bin/sudo rm -rf /var/core
        /usr/local/bin/sudo rm -rf /var/audit
        files=`/usr/local/bin/sudo /usr/bin/find /var/adm -xdev -type f -size +1000000000c -exec ls -lht {} \; | awk '{ print $9}'`
        files1=`/usr/local/bin/sudo /usr/bin/find /var/adm/log -xdev -type f -size +1000000000c -exec ls -lht {} \; | awk '{ print $9}'`
        files2=`/usr/local/bin/sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log -xdev -type f -size +1000000000c -exec ls -lht {} \; | awk '{ print $9}'`
        echo "$files" >>/tmp/files.log
        echo "$files1" >>/tmp/files.log
        echo "$files2" >>/tmp/files.log
        for i in `cat /tmp/files.log`
        do
            echo $i
            /usr/local/bin/sudo tar -cf $i_$date.tar $i
            /usr/local/bin/sudo gzip $i_$date.tar
            /usr/local/bin/sudo rm $i_$date.tar
            /usr/local/bin/sudo cp /dev/null $i
        done
    fi
    if [ ${chk} -gt ${threshold} ]; then
        echo "$(hostname): Fileystem Warning on ${fs} is used: ${chk}%."
        sudo /usr/bin/find ${fs} -xdev -type f -size +100000000c -exec ls -lht {} \;
        echo " -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    fi
done
```

Comment: On a Mac, using `gzip -v9 ~/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd.msd` from a wholly different directory (`~/soq`), I get the output:  `/Users/jleffler/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd.msd:    79.9% -- replaced with /Users/jleffler/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd.msd.gz` — that is, the file is gzipped 'in situ'.  Further, the original file is removed.  Therefore, you should not need to remove the original, and the gzipped file should be in the correct location already.

Comment: If that doesn't happen on Solaris, you should investigate whether you're using an archaic `gzip` (though I've never come across a version doing what you say is happening), or you need to review whether NFS and root privileges are somehow screwing things up, or what.  You could print out the file names as they're processed to ensure you see what's going on (what is the output from the `echo $i`?).  You could use the `-v9` option to see what `gzip` is doing.  You could add `set -x;` before the `$(<.fs1.sh)`.  Something should tell you what's up.  The number of invocations of `sudo` worries me.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the output of `gzip` to stdout by using the `-c` switch and specify the output file.

```
gzip -c $i_$date.tar > /path/to/original/dir/new.gz
```

Comment: thanks but if files are in 5 different location we don't know right.      need to zip on same location.. if its possible                                                                    
    -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        856M Jun 27 06:45 /var/log/mail.log_27.06.17.gz
-rw-------   1 root     root         16G Aug 20 12:35 /var/log/mail.log
-rw-------   1 root     root        7.9G Aug  8 03:10 /var/adm/messages.1
-rw-------   1 root     root        6.1G Aug 20 12:35 /var/adm/messages
-rw-rw----   1 root     mail        1.5G Aug 20 12:26 /var/mail/root

Comment: here just i need need to find out the more then 1gb file on on /var/adm location and need to zip it and and nully the existing file this is what i need, please help on this on any way

Comment: here the destination path have to take it from the output logs.                                                /usr/local/bin/sudo /usr/bin/find /var/adm -xdev -type f -size +1000000000c -exec ls -lht {} \; | awk '{ print $9}'`

Comment: ksh[18]: /var/log/daemon.log_08-30-17.tar.gz: cannot create
i am getting this error                                                                                          for i in `cat /tmp/files.log`
                do
                echo $i >>/tmp/check.log
    /usr/local/bin/sudo tar -cf ${i}_${date}.tar $i
     /usr/local/bin/sudo gzip ${i}_${date}.tar > ${i}_${date}.tar.gz
     /usr/local/bin/sudo rm ${i}_${date}.tar
                /usr/local/bin/sudo cp /dev/null ${i}
                done
                  fi